# Dual Boot on a HP Dragonfly Elite Laptop

Tags: linux, dual-boot, laptop, hp

I'm facing some trouble like never before. Recently I got a [HP Dragonfly Laptop](https://www8.hp.com/us/en/laptops/2-in-1s/elite-dragonfly-convertible.html) and obviously it comes with Windows, I've tried to install Linux many times and many flavors (Ubuntu, Fedora, Elementary OS, etc.) but none has succeed.

The problem I believe is the partitioning of the disk. It's a NVMe and it comes with Intel Optane, I didn't want to lose it because of Windows.

I can use any Linux distro on LiveUSB, I theoretically install it, but when it finish and restarts the laptop it loads Windows automatically.

My partitions installation was as follow:

- /boot partition of 512MB (ext4)
- Creation of a physical encrypted partition
- / partition and format (ext4)

I've tried to install the GRUB on the first disk that appears and also on the "Intel Optane" hidden disk and none of them works.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

I'm attaching a picture of my current disk partitions in Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently fighting against the same issue as you. At the moment I understand that it is impossible to change the boot order due to UEFI, if you want to disable UEFI you have to disable HP's secure boot, then disable Intel's rapid storage tech in windows then disable Optane in the UEFI settings (accessible via the bios or from an advanced restart) then you should be able to choose legacy mode and boot into grub.
That is my understanding of the situation and since there is risk of losing data I didn't do these steps myself yet.
It's overly complicated and I don't understand why since it was really easy before.
All the info I shared comes from different forums and websites, don't take my word for it.
Hopefully I'm wrong and there is an easier way to dual boot onto linux. Good luck